# what is a reliable way to return number of records inserted from a stored procedure

Tags: c#, sql, stored-procedures, insert

I am using *INSERT Trigger* on that table. Once trigger is executed (it update the table if a condition is meet), that is where the problem is.

```
  int records = sc.ExecuteNonQuery(); // works ok if trigger does not update the record
```

The above code always ruturns -1 if I leave `SET NOCOUNT ON;` in the stored procedure itself. If I remove it, I get correct result but if trigger does update the record, then wrong result. I sometime get 10 or a different number. My Trigger looks like this

```
UPDATE students 
    SET status = 'Inactive'

    FROM Inserted i
        INNER JOIN students T2
            ON i.sname = T2.sname
            AND i.id <> t2.id
```

That means it can return more than one record (esp in test cases). Can someone tell me what is the cure? I am open to use Functions if that solves the problem or any better approach.

Thanks

### Adding Insert SP

```
CREATE PROCEDURE sp_InsertSudent 
    -- Add the parameters for the stored procedure here
    @student_name varchar(25) = null, 
    @status varchar(20) = null,
    @renew varchar(15) = null,
    @edate datetime = null
AS
BEGIN

    --SET NOCOUNT ON;

    insert into students VALUES(@student_name,@status,@renew,@edate)


END
GO
```

Note: I am looking for an error because the fields are picked from Excel. if any field is in wrong format or empty, the Insert SP will produce error. I must convey that error to the user.

### Adding Actual SP

So the whole problem is in the SP. If I remove it, everything works fine. Here is my actual SP

```
UPDATE CustomerTbl
SET [Account Status] = 'Inactive',
    [End Date] = DateAdd(day,-1,[Supplier End Date]),
    [EnrollmentStatus] = 'Waiting'
WHERE OET.[Account No] = (SELECT [Account No] FROM CustomerTbl WHERE id = @@identity)
  AND id <> @@identity
```

The logic is the same as above but stated differently. The ExecuteNonQuery oupts the result of this trigger than than the actual storedprocedure, so what is he cure? Can suppress its output somehow.

Comment: I think it should be executeScaler instead, i though it fixed that somewhere else already. ExecuteScaler did not work

Comment: Don't you know how may rows you are inserting?

Comment: I insert one row at a time but there can be 10 rows waiting to be inserted so all are inserted one by one in a loop (C# code) by calling a stored Procedure. So technically SP is called 10 times for 10 records and Insert is called 10 times? I am not an expert :(

Comment: So you can ignore the bnumber of records back from the INSERT. It is always "1"

Comment: No assume, there were errors in the parameters so the record will not be inserted in that case. That call should return 0, the successful call return 1.

Comment: Trigger are evil. If you can avoid them, you should.

Comment: Are you able to add `SET NOCOUNT ON` to your trigger code? It's usually recommended to have that present anyway.

Comment: Jonas Elfström, that's just silly. Triggers are often the best way to ensure data integrity. ANd looking at that trigger, it is a required trigger because he is inactivating any old records. That must be done at the datbase level or a change not through the appication will break the integirty of the data.

Comment: Yes with that ON, it always return -1 weather a record is inserted or not. Success/failure does not matter in that case.

Comment: updated with actual SP. The problem is with SP, if I remove it everything works fine. ExecuteNonQuery() outputs the records from the tigger instead of SP.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My own answer (not complete yet). [According to MSDN documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.executenonquery.aspx) for ExecuteNonQuery

> When a trigger exists on a table being inserted or updated, the return
>   value includes the number of rows affected by both the insert or
>   update operation and the number of rows affected by the trigger or
>   triggers.

This means I need to modify the trigger itself to accommodate the logic, or even by the fact that when trigger is called, that proves that a record was successful. That means if I get anything greater than 0, that should be assumed as success. Although not solid logic but it will work. SET COUNT ON must be commented for this.

Answer (score 0):

maybe I'm not understanding the question, but if your goal is to track the number of rows *inserted*, then you would maintain a count of how many times you're calling your stored procedure (assuming your sproc inserts one row at a time, of course).

alternately, if you are trying to maintain a count of the total # of records affected (by both inserts and updates), then you could incorporate the logic in the trigger into your sproc. the rows affected by both the insert statement (always 1) and by the update statement (@@rowcount after update completes) ... you could then return that value to the caller.

UPDATE:
Sure, return 0 if there is an error. If using SQL2005 (or above), use TRY/CATCH mechanism.

Comment: goal is total number of *successfull* rows inserted. An insert can be unsuccessful if there were errors in the parameter, e.g, number inserted in datetime field. I am not interested in the result of INSERT trigger at all, and I dont want to keep any eye on it (may be in future).

Answer (score 0):

I would add Try Catch blocks to the proc and have it return 1 if successful and 0 if not successful.

I also would adjust the trigger to be more efficient by only chaning the status of those where are active and meet the other criteria.

```
UPDATE students      
SET status = 'Inactive'      
FROM Inserted i         
INNER JOIN students T2             
    ON i.sname = T2.sname 
    AND i.id <> t2.id 
    AND status <> 'inactive'
```

This could save you from updating 1000 rows when you only really need to update one active row.

Answer (score 0):

Add an extra column that the stored proc doesnt populate (leaves null)
then when the trigger runs, simply update the Null values to a non-null value and use the RowCount from the Update to determine how many rows were updated.